# load image from url with arabic characters

Tags: android, url, utf-8

In my application i need to load images from several urls into a Gridview.
The problem is that my urls contain arabic characters and images aren't downloaded.
I tested my app with English url and it's working fine, but i have problem with arabic ones.
I have tried this to decode url but it's not working:

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode(imageUrls.get(j), "UTF-8");
```

also tried this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

Snippet to download bitmap:

```
for(j=0; j<imageUrls.size(); j++){
    try {
    String result = URLDecoder.decode(imageUrls.get(j), "UTF-8");
        URL url=new URL(result);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        btarray.add(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    }
```

and have

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(btarray.get(position));
```

in ImageAdapter getView method.

urls are like this: 
http://www.dalass.com/1/ShowPage.php?View=252-%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AE%D9%86-DALASS-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3.jpg

somebody help please

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: I have imageviews with null image in gridview

Comment: Use Shutterbug library. Its easy to use and reliable. https://github.com/applidium/Shutterbug

Comment: @MayuriRuparel
My problem is with arabic urls, not loading images. Could this library load images from arabis urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `Uri.encode(String)`

```
   //String result = URLDecoder.decode(imageUrls.get(j), "UTF-8");
   String result = Uri.encode(imageUrls.get(j));
   URL url = new URL(result);
```

Comment: by using decode i have imageviews whith null images, but when using encode i have a blank gridview without any imageview

Comment: I found that problem was with the url; that was a web url instead of an image url. By fixing this mistake encode worked correctly.

Comment: I have the exact same issue can you tell me how you fixed it please

Comment: `.toString()` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
String encodeUriString = Uri.encode(uri.getLastPathSegment());
String uriString = uri.toString().replace(uri.getLastPathSegment(), encodeUriString);
Log.d(TAG, uriString);
```